# list object has no attribute copy

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

```
feed_obj = self.get_feed_obj(request, kwargs.get('feed_id'))
        ad_ingredient_id = kwargs.get('ad_ingredient_id')
        adingredient_obj = AdIngredient.objects.filter(feed_id=feed_obj.id, created_by_id=request.user.id, state=1).first()
        for data in self.data_formating(request, feed_obj):
            serializer = self.serializer_class(adingredient_obj,data=data,partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
            else:
                return Response(
                    {
                        'success': False,
                        'detail': serializer.errors
                    },
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                )
        return Response(
            {
                'success': True,
                'detail': 'Feed Ad Ingredients information updated successfully',
                'data': feed_obj.id
            },
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

It is not updating data, it keeps brining the older data which is added when the object was created.

AttributeError at /api/feeds/ad-ingredient/55/
'list' object has no attribute 'copy'

Traceback:

File "/Users/omairbukhari/env_justads/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/omairbukhari/env_justads/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/Users/omairbukhari/env_justads/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/omairbukhari/env_justads/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/omairbukhari/env_justads/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/omairbukhari/env_justads/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  83.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/omairbukhari/env_justads/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  477.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/Users/omairbukhari/env_justads/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  437.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/Users/omairbukhari/env_justads/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  474.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/omairbukhari/justads/backend/feeds/views.py" in update
  738.         request_data = request.data.copy()

Comment: `list.copy` was introduced in Python 3.3. If you are using Python 2.7 you should probably downgrade the version of django you are using. In the future please provide the entire stack trace.

Comment: I have added the traceback.... I hope it will help you in locating the problem ....

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 1):

`list.copy` was introduced in Python 3.3.

You are using Python 2.7 hence you should downgrade the version of django you are using (to `1.11`):

From [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django):

```
Django version  Python versions
1.11            2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6
2.0             3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7
2.1, 2.2        3.5, 3.6, 3.7
```

**Update**

See the last line in the stack trace:

```
File "/Users/omairbukhari/justads/backend/feeds/views.py" in update 738. 
     request_data = request.data.copy()
```

Instead, use an empty slicing: `request_data = request.data[:]`

If this is **not** your code, you did not downgrade django's version correctly.

Comment: I have checked my version. Here is what it says
"list indices must be integers, not str"